# Angular v6 SwalAlert2 always show a checkbox. I did not put it in there. How can I fix it?

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

```
import { default as swal } from 'sweetalert2';

swal({ title: 'Cargando..!', text: 'Espere por favor', allowOutsideClick: false, allowEscapeKey: false,
                allowEnterKey: false, onOpen: () => { swal.showLoading()} });
```

The image shows a loader and the checkbox that i don't want

[image: The image shows a loader and the checkbox that i don't want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.

(1) See if sweetalert2 provides an option to hide the checkbox.

(2) Use CSS to hide the checkbox

Since components should not manipulate the CSS of their children you should either put your CSS in the global stylesheet - styles.css - OR within the components stylesheet target the checkbox using `::ng-deep` (deprecated)

example:

styles.css

```
.annoying-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
```

OR your.component.css

```
::ng-deep .annoying-checkbox {
  display: none; 
}
```